# Tratando JSON associativo em PHP

Tags: php, java, json, retrofit

Tenho uma aplicação Java:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(pedido);

    DataServiceGenerator dataServiceGenerator = new DataServiceGenerator();
    Webservice service = dataServiceGenerator.createService(Webservice.class);
    Call<String> call = service.postJson(json);
```

Retrofit:

```
@POST("/servidor.php")
Call<String> postJson(@Body String pedido);
```

Como posso recuperar estes dados para salvar em uma tabela no php:

```
[{
"ped_data_hora": {
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 6,
    "dayOfMonth": 4,
    "hourOfDay": 23,
    "minute": 47,
    "second": 51
},
"ped_hor_ent_producao": {
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 6,
    "dayOfMonth": 4,
    "hourOfDay": 23,
    "minute": 47,
    "second": 51
},
"ped_hor_retorno": {
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 6,
    "dayOfMonth": 4,
    "hourOfDay": 23,
    "minute": 47,
    "second": 51
},
"ped_hor_sai_producao": {
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 6,
    "dayOfMonth": 4,
    "hourOfDay": 23,
    "minute": 47,
    "second": 51
},
"ped_hor_saida": {
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 6,
    "dayOfMonth": 4,
    "hourOfDay": 23,
    "minute": 47,
    "second": 51
},
"ped_programado": {
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 6,
    "dayOfMonth": 4,
    "hourOfDay": 23,
    "minute": 47,
    "second": 51
},
"ped_repique": {
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 6,
    "dayOfMonth": 4,
    "hourOfDay": 23,
    "minute": 47,
    "second": 51
},
"campo1": 1,
"campo2": 2,
"campo3": 3,
"campo4": 4
}]
```

Já tentei assim:

```
 $resultado=json_decode(json_encode( $_POST ), true );
... $resultado->ped_data_hora;
... $resultado[0]->ped_data_hora;
... $resultado['campo1'];
```

Assim:

```
$resultado=json_decode($_POST);
```

Já verifiquei e minha JSON está valida, só não consigo obter os valores;

Comment: Qual é o resultado que obteve em suas duas tentativas?

Comment: null ou falha na decodificação

Comment: ERRO: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'campo1' cannot be null

Comment: Ok, mas esse é um erro no SQL, não tem relação com a leitura do JSON.

Comment: Mas confesso que estou meio perdido com a lógica de tratamento, já que tenho parte associativa na json, e parte não

Comment: sim, mas tanto com um echo ou diretamente ao sql, apresenta resultado nulo

Comment: quando dou um var_dump(), retorna isto: array(0) {}

Comment: Aliás, seu JSON não é válido, não. `"campo4": 4,` esta vírgula no final não pode existir.

Comment: Correto, eu removi alguns campos e deixei ela, vou editar!

Comment: Pensando melhor, onde é que entra o JSON aí? Se você recebe os dados via `$_POST`, ele já será um *array*. Não faz sentido convertê-lo para JSON e depois voltar a *array*; bem como não faz sentido você decodificar o JSON em um *array*. O que **exatamente** você quer fazer?

Comment: está parte que estou perdido então, estou enviando de um cliente java uma json com dados de uma classe convertidos para json, e preciso salvar estes dados numa tabela mysql no servidor

Comment: E como você está enviando esses dados? Essa informação deveria estar na pergunta, assim como essa descrição do problema que comentou.

Comment: os dados vão exatamente como coloquei na json, a questão era como manipular ela do lado servidor, mas vou complementar então

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79772/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-rodrigo).

Answer (score 0):

Foi resolvido com a ajuda do colega [Anderson Carlos Woss](http://Anderson%20Carlos%20Woss), segue:

```
$resultado = json_decode(json_decode($json), false );
```

Dai trabalho com os objetos desta maneira:

```
$resultado[0]->campo1
```

E assim:

```
$resultado[0]->campo1->sub_campo
```

E mais uma dica importante referente a datas, que é o meu caso, para salvar em um campo Date() no mysql por exemplo, segue a dica:

```
$data = $resultado[0]->ped_hor_ent_producao;
$formatada = "{$data->year}/{$data->month}/{$data->day}";
```